# javascript websql code value in output is undefined despite of storing value in it

Tags: javascript, html

```
var db = openDatabase('tournament', '1.0', 'Scoring', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

var msg;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql("SELECT ballno FROM app_t20_balldetails order by ballno desc", [],
    function(tx, result)
    {
      msg =  result.rows.item(0).ballno;
     alert(msg);
    });
});

 alert(msg);
```

This code shows two alert messages one with `7` and second `undefined`. What can i do to get value 7 in both alert meassages?

Comment: The WebSQL API you are using is *asynchronous*. The `db.transaction(...)` call only prepares to execute the transaction, but doesn't immediately call it. This is basically the same principle as AJAX calls, you need to use a callback. Read through [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) , that should give you a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fetchBallNo = function (callback){

    var db = window.openDatabase('tournament', '1.0', 'Scoring', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

    var msg;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT ballno FROM app_t20_balldetails order by ballno desc", [],
                function(tx, result)
                {
            msg =  result.rows.item(0).ballno;
            alert(msg);
                });
    }, function(tx, error) {
        window.alert("Transaction Error: " + error + tx.message);
        callback(null);
    }, function(tx) {
        callback(msg);
    });
};

fetchBallNo(function(msg){
    if(msg) {
        window.alert(msg);
    } else {
        window.alert('Value not found');
    }
});
```

This will help you get the same output in both the alerts.
Since, Websql API is asynchronous you have to either use a callback

or

use JQuery deffered promises, you may find the details for the second way in here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/